# How to set ActiveMQ to stop accepting messages?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, qpid

I want to know that in ActiveMQ is there any property with which user can restrict ActiveMQ to not  accept the messages in an Input Queue after a certain threshold is reached ?
So far i am able to find out its flow control using **memory constraint**.
I want to **dynamically block my input queue** when input queue reaches its certain threshold.
Is there any other software which can help me to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible way is to plug custom [broker interceptor](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html) into ActiveMQ.

Supple your Spring broker configuration with:

```
<plugins>
  <bean id="myPlugin" class="org.foo.CheckThresholdPlugin"/>    
</plugins>
```

Then extend [BrokerPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerFilter.html) to override **send** method.

```java
package org.foo;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerPlugin;

public class CheckThresholdPlugin extends BrokerFilter { 

    public void send(ProducerBrokerExchange producer, Message message) throws Exception {     
        boolean isOverThreshold = /* figure it out by getting Destination from Message */
        if (isOverThreshold) {
          throw new Exception("The threshold is exceeded.");
        } else {
          super.send(producer, message);
        }
    }

}
```